# Pandas read Json - Trailing Data

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I am trying to read a large Json file through Pandas pd.read_json, but an error is showing:
ValueError: Trailing data

From my research here I was not successful, so I would like to ask for your help.
Tried to run a Json validator and the output is below.

How can I fix this? Thank you

[image: Error from Json Validator]

[image: line 191 - JSON file]

Comment: There is probably a bad character in your JSON that is being improperly parsed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messeage you presented contains precise location where the
source of the problem is:

```
(At line #191), (At position #1)
```

Look at the indicated place in your JSON file.

## Edit

A weird detail in your file is that the comma should be **after** "}" in
line 190, not a the beginning of the next line, but I'm not sure whether
this is actually any problem.

Attempt "partial reading", without the object starting at line 191.

One more detail to check: If "}" in line 190 terminates the **whole** above
content, then:

- your input file contains **multiple** JSON objects at the main level,
- probably you should enclose the whole file with "[" and "]", so that
  the whole file will be a list of objects.

## Edit 2

I made such an experiment:

Input file contains:

```
{
  "aa" : "aa1",
  "bb" : "bb1"
},
{
  "aa" : "aa2",
  "bb" : "bb2"
}
```

(2 JSON objects at the main level).

Then `pd.read_json('Input.json')` raised *ValueError: Trailing data*.

But when I changed the input file to:

```
[
  {
    "aa" : "aa1",
    "bb" : "bb1"
  },
  {
    "aa" : "aa2",
    "bb" : "bb2"
  }
]
```

(a **list** of 2 JSON objects), I got a proper result:

```
    aa   bb
0  aa1  bb1
1  aa2  bb2
```

Look at your input file, maybe in your case the problem is just like
I showed.

**Yet another experinent**

Input file contains:

```
{ "aa" : "aa1", "bb" : "bb1" }
{ "aa" : "aa2", "bb" : "bb2" }
{ "aa" : "aa3", "bb" : "bb3" }
```

i.e. separate objects, **without** surrounding "[" and "]" either with
or without comma after each object.

You can read it calling `pd.read_json('Input.json', lines=True)`.

But the limitation here is that each line must contain **complete** JSON
object, so in your case it is rather useless.

Comment: Thank you! I've done that, but  the thing is I do not see anything wrong. Added the image above. Any idea?

Comment: Attempt to use another JSON validator. Or if you have enough patience, delete a part of your file, without the "problematic" region (saving it in another file) and try to read it.

Comment: thank you very much! your suggestion on "Edit 2" worked!