# lines=True parameter for the Json Type Provider and Json.Net library?

Tags: f#, json.net, f#-data

I am working on this [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/stanford-covid-vaccine) competition.  The Jupyter notebooks on Kaggle only support R and Python and I wanted to use F# locally.  The problem is that the datasets are .json files and both the F# Json Type Provider and Newtonsoft libraries fail when trying to parse the files.

Here are examples of the code failing in F#:

```
open FSharp.Data
type Context = JsonProvider<"train.json">
let context = Context.
```

and

```
open System
open System.IO
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let object = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("train.json"));
object
```

[This](https://www.kaggle.com/allohvk/eda-some-additional-features-rc-pair-distance) Python example uses these line of code to parse them correctly:

```
train = pd.read_json('../input/stanford-covid-vaccine/train.json', lines=True)
test = pd.read_json('../input/stanford-covid-vaccine/test.json', lines=True)
```

In the notebook, the author says that without the "lines=True" parameter, the read_json method fails with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716765/pandas-read-json-trailing-data) trailing error.

My question: assuming tis is the same error, is there a way to apply that same kind of "lines=true" to the .NET libraries to parse the json?

Comment: I'd bet that's not a valid JSON string in the first place. Instead of a JSON array, I bet it's one unindented JSON string per line. JSON simply doesn't allow multiple root elements. Storing one JSON object per line though is a common way to store lots of data, as it allows appending new records, partitioning the data files etc.

Comment: BTW this is just a technique used by all companies that handle lots of data (not necessarily big data) but some copycats tried to push it as a "standard" and even "borrowed" text from Doug Crockford's `json.org` site or the ECMA/W3C standards. It's still not a standard, just a technique used by a *lot* of companies long before the copycats

Comment: Newtonsoft can read newline-delimited JSON if you use a `JsonTextReader` and set its `SupportMultipleContent` flag to true.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38429059/10263) for an example in C#.  If you can translate to F# it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few datasets where the format was one valid JSON record per line:

```
{"event":"nothing 1"}
{"event":"nothing 2"}
{"event":"nothing 3"}
```

This is not valid JSON overall. I think you can either parse it line-by-line or you can turn it into valid JSON. For line-by-line parsing (which may be more efficient as you can do this in a streaming fashion), I would use:

```
open FSharp.Data
type Log = JsonProvider<"""{"event":"nothing 1"}""">

for line in File.ReadAllLines("some.json") do
  let l = Log.Parse(line)
  printfn "%s" l.Event
```